# mandelbrot set: computer running out of decimal places for zoom

Tags: complex-numbers

I was trying to render a mandelbrot zoom in python but after a while everything became blocky because there weren't enough decimal places in my computer memory to contain the detail. i'm using this function:

- $z = $screen coordinates
- $c = z$
- $z.x = (z.x^2 - z.y^2)+c.x$
- $z.y = (2×z.x×z.y)+x.y$

When I zoom in I multiply the screen coordinates by a certain value. Every zero at the end of this value causes the screen coordinates to move up one place. Computers have limited accuracy so eventually i run out of decimal places to store location data. I end up with a blocky image like this: [blocky image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXNr3.png).

---

I need a solution or an alternative equation to fix the issue.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This is not with these four lines that we can have any idea why and how you are running short of precision and therefore be able to help you...

Comment: You might try doing the computations with arbitrary precision arithmetic.  A quick Google search finds [mpmath](https://mpmath.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the floating point precision to any level you choose using the [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) library. Extremely high precision will eventually start making the computation slower though, so there'll still be some practical limit to how far you can zoom in.

A comment above mentions the [mpmath](https://mpmath.org/doc/current/basics.html) library. This is another way to get a correct implementation, but your code will run slower than it would with `Decimal`. That's because `mpmath` is written in Python, while `Decimal` is running faster C code behind the scenes ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67936263/18086074)).

In general it'll probably be hard to get a massively better result than just using your existing computation with higher floating point precisions. The computation depends heavily on tiny differences in the inputs - that's why the boundary of the fractal is so complicated in the first place.